# ordenar numeros con pilas

Tags: c++, algoritmos, c++11, pilas

Quisiera optimizar un algoritmo pero ya no se me ocurren mas ideas es sobre ordenar números con pilas: El ejercicio consta de que el usuario mete datos en dos pilas y de ahí debo de imprimir el mínimo numero de movimientos en los cuales los datos sean ordenados supongamos.

Si muevo un dato de la pila A hacia B debo de imprimir el numero de movimientos en caso contrario igual es lo mismo pero con signo negativo. Cuando encuentre el menor dato en una de las pilas ya sea A o B debo de imprimir que dato saque si fue de la pila A o B el chiste es que los datos salgan ordenados con el más mínimo numero de movimientos.

Entrada

```
3 1
2 4 1
3
```

Salida

```
A
1
A
-1
B
A
```

El problema que tengo con mi código es cuando tengo números repetidos en lugar de que saque los datos de una pila que esta mas cerca del tope saca los otros elementos de la otra pila pero sobre pasa el mínimo numero de movimientos 
este es mi código:

```
//declaramos nuestra libreria estandar STL en c++ para instancia nuestras dos pilas y manejarlas mas facil
//descartamos el uso de la clase pila porque no contiene iteradores
//y son necesarios para copiar datos de pila a un vector al igual de
//utilizar la busqueda binaria tampoco podemos utilizarla en la clase pila por el iterador

#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

//esta plantilla que hacemos lo que hace es forzar a la clase pila tener su iterador y asi poder copiar datos hacia el vector
template< typename T > typename T::container_type &subyacent_container( T &stack ) {
    struct Aux : public T {
    using T::c;
    };
  return static_cast< Aux & >( stack ).c;
}

namespace std {
    template< typename T > typename T::container_type::iterator begin( T &o ) { return subyacent_container( o ).begin( ); }

    template< typename T > typename T::container_type::iterator end( T &o ) { return subyacent_container( o ).end( ); }

}

void showstack(stack <int> s) 
{ 
    while (!s.empty()) 
    { 
        cout << '\t' << s.top(); 
        s.pop(); 
    } 
    cout << '\n'; 
} 

int main(){
    //leemos los datos de que van estar en nuestras dos pilas
    int n1, n2;
    int dato1, dato2; //creamos dos variables como auxiliares para que vayamos leyendos los datos de cada una de las pilas
    cin >> n1 >> n2; //leemos las longitudes de cada una de las pilas
    stack <int> A, B; //creamos nuestras dos pilas
    //vector<int> indices1[1000],indices2[1000];
    while(n1--){
            cin >> dato1;
            //A1.push_back(dato1);
            A.push(dato1);
    }
    while(n2--){
        cin >> dato2;
       // B1.push_back(dato2);
        B.push(dato2);
    }

   /*     cout << "The stack is A: "; 
        showstack(A); 
        cout << "The stack is B: "; 
        showstack(B);*/
        int cuentaA, cuentaB;
        while( !A.empty() || !B.empty() ){ //hasta que las dos pilas queden vacias
        //hacemos la copia de una pila hacia un vector
        vector<int> A1( begin( A ), end( A ) );
        vector<int> B1( begin( B), end( B ) );
       // vector<int> aux; //este vector va a comparar si el tope 
      /*  for(int i = A1.size()-1; i >= 0 ; i--){
            cout << A1[i] << " ";
        }
            cout << endl;
        for(int j = B1.size()-1; j >= 0 ; j--){
            cout << B1[j] << " ";
        }*/
        if( !A.empty() && !B.empty() ){ //este if checa si las pilas estan llenas
            sort(A1.begin(),A1.end()); //ordenamos nuestros vectores
            sort(B1.begin(),B1.end());
            cuentaA = 0;
            cuentaB = 0;
            if( A1[0] < B1[0] ){
                 while( A1[0] != A.top() ){ //si A1[0] == A.top se sale del ciclo
                          B.push(A.top()); //pasamos el tope del dato A hacia B
                          A.pop(); //sacamos el dato en A
                          cuentaA++;
                }//fin del while para sacar los datos de la pila A hacia B
                //cout << endl;
                if( cuentaA > 0){ //solamente imprimos la cuentaA si hubo movimientos 
                    cout << cuentaA << endl; }
                cout << "A" << endl; //significa que sacamos el dato menor de la pila A
                A.pop();
                /*showstack(A);
                showstack(B);*/
            }//fin del if para comparar el dato menor que exista en la pila A
            else{ //if( B1[0] < A1[0]){
                cuentaB = 0;
                while( B1[0] != B.top() ){ //si B1[0] == B.top se sale del ciclo
                    A.push(B.top()); //pasamos el tope del dato B hacia A
                    B.pop(); //sacamos el dato en B
                    cuentaB++;
            }//fin del while para sacar los datos de la pila A hacia B
            //cout << endl;
            if( cuentaB > 0){ //solamente imprimimos la cuentaB si hubo movimientos
                cout << "-" << cuentaB << endl; }
            cout << "B" << endl; //significa que sacamos el dato menor de la pila A
            B.pop();
            /*showstack(A);
            showstack(B);*/
            } //fin del else para comparar el dato menor que exista en la pila B
       }/*fin del if para las pilas A y B si estan llenas*/ 
       else{
             if( !A.empty() && B.empty() ){ //si la pila B esta vacia y la pila A esta llena entra 
                sort(A1.begin(),A1.end()); //ordenamos nuestro vector
                cuentaA = 0;
                while( A1[0] != A.top() ){ //si A1[0] == A.top se sale del ciclo
                          B.push(A.top()); //pasamos el tope del dato A hacia B
                          A.pop(); //sacamos el dato en A
                          cuentaA++;
                        }//fin del while para sacar los datos de la pila A hacia B
                //cout << endl;
                if( cuentaA > 0){ //solamente imprimos la cuentaA si hubo movimientos 
                    cout << cuentaA << endl; }
                cout << "A" << endl; //significa que sacamos el dato menor de la pila A
                A.pop();
               /* showstack(A);
                if( !B.empty() ) { //solamente muestra la pila B si tiene datos
                showstack(B); }*/

            }//fin del if si la pila A esta llena y pila B vacia
            else{//if(!B.empty() && A.empty()){ //si la pila A esta vacia y la pila B esta llena entra
                sort(B1.begin(),B1.end()); //ordenamos nuestro vector
                cuentaB = 0;
                while( B1[0] != B.top() ){ //si B1[0] == B.top se sale del ciclo
                             A.push(B.top()); //pasamos el tope del dato B hacia A
                             B.pop(); //sacamos el dato en B
                             cuentaB++;
                    }//fin del while para sacar los datos de la pila A hacia B
                 //cout << endl;
                 if( cuentaB > 0){ //solamente imprimimos la cuentaB si hubo movimientos
                    cout << "-" << cuentaB << endl; }
                 cout << "B" << endl; //significa que sacamos el dato menor de la pila A
                 B.pop();
                /* if( !A.empty() ){//si la pila A tiene datos lo imprime
                 showstack(A); }
                 showstack(B);*/
             }//fin del else si la pila B esta llena y la pila A esta vacia
        }//fin del else en caso de que una de las pilas A o B esten vacias

    }//fin del while hasta que las dos pilas queden vacias    
    cout << endl;
    return 0;
}
/*tengo la idea de implementar quicksort pero no se como para las dos pilas de modo que imprima el numero minimo de movimientos*/
```

Comment: Encontrar el camino mínimo para ordenar la secuencia no es trivial. No solo depende de si el número a extraer está duplicado en ambas pilas... elegir en este caso el camino más corto te puede desviar del camino más corto a nivel global. Este tipo de ejercicios están para darle al coco ya que no basta con que el programa funcione sino que debe hacerlo bajo unas condiciones muy concretas. Dudo que alguien se estudie el problema tan a fondo como para darte una solución

Comment: si es un ejercicio de la ACM de los concursos de programacion en si pz si me salio el problema es que no me lo acepta el juez online que lo califica porque se pasa de tiempo espero y encontrar la solucion optima para este ejercicio